# Best place to find coding partners for open-source projects?

Tags: open-source, project, collaboration

I find myself wanting to develop certain projects, but most of the time I lack motivation because I develop by myself.

What I usually do is look for similar existing projects, and ask the developers if they like to collaborate, but it's rather hard.

Is there a good place (a website maybe) to find people that are interested in the same project as me, and therefore would like to collaborate?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You code by yourself?

Release the code on one of the open-source foundries. (code.google.com. sf.net. bitbucket.org , github.com ,etc...)

Pick an easy license (x11/MIT is good, GPL2/3/AGPL3 if you like, among others.)

Write simple instructions on how to deploy, run, with a one-page tutorial.

Have a website where you write about the stuff you build, and the stuff you'd like to build.

Find people who need some help and help them. Don't over-extend yourself.

It takes time to build trust. Trust takes time.

## Update

You wrote:

> What I usually do is look for similar existing projects, and ask the developers if they like to collaborate, but it's rather hard.

If you see an open-source project out there, odds are the developers already like to collaborate. What they might not want to do is talk about grand schemes about how to turn the software into the next fifty billion-dollar behemoth. Generally, if you join the mailing list, introduce yourself ("Hi, I'm Joe, and I like to do X, and I like this software."), get and **use** the software, and provide feedback and *constructive* criticism, and demonstrate that you are following instructions or at least attempting to, and then, then, if you provide a patch (or a branch if github) it might be looked at and considered.

Do follow the project methodology. For example, if they use tests, submit tests with your patch, that sort of thing.

Answer (score 6):

I tried myself to start an open source project and failed. I had published my idea in a forum and there were about 10 or 15 people who wanted to join the project. Actually there were very little activity ...

I think the main reason for the failure was that I hadn't developed anything before going public. It would have been really useful to have at least a prototype. Another thing is defining a (simple) development process.

If I would try it again, I would:

- develop a prototype
- document the code and the architecture in detail
- write down tasks others could do
- describe the development process
- design a nice website and promote my work
- publish the code at google code or something like that

Comment: +1 for sharing this. This reminds me of a passage from __The Cathedral and the Bazaar__: "When you start community-building, what you need to be able to present is a plausible promise. Your program doesn't have to work particularly well. It can be crude, buggy, incomplete, and poorly documented. What it must not fail to do is (a) run, and (b) convince potential co-developers that it can be evolved into something really neat in the foreseeable future." (http://catb.org/esr/writings/cathedral-bazaar/cathedral-bazaar/ar01s10.html)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the offerings at github.com. If you can use git, I often find some cool projects on there, and you can always fork the repository to help out.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should register your project on an Open Source Forge. There is a comparison list on  Wikipedia : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_software_hosting_facilities

On certain forges, there is a way to ask for help. I know that SourceForge does: https://sourceforge.net/people/

I recommend that you read Karl Fogel's excellent and complete book on the subject : [Producing Open Source Software](http://producingoss.com/). It is freely available online or in print from Amazon.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have some code somewhere online, you could put an ad for your project on [Stack Overflow's Open Source Advertising](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93312/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2011).

Quote from the link:

> It must be an advertisement **soliciting the participation and
>   contribution of programmers writing actual source code**. This is not
>   intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just
>   happen to be open source. It's for finding programmers who will help
>   contribute code or other programmery things (documentation, code
>   review, bug fixes, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

[Openhatch](https://openhatch.org/)
is the best place I have found to look for open source projects